# Webfinger support for OpenID login?

Tags: feature-request, openid, login

Now that host-meta has [been standardized](http://groups.google.com/group/webfinger/browse_thread/thread/220cce0b3e0d48ba) in [RFC 6415](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6415), will Stack Exchange implement [WebFinger](http://code.google.com/p/webfinger/) support for their OpenID login? It's a [draft at the IETF](http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-jones-appsawg-webfinger-00.txt) now.

That way I wouldn't need to type in my OpenID URL anymore, but could simply use my e-mail when logging in, and the OpenID would be discovered automatically.

---

> users didn't want or were to be confused by email-like identifiers.

It's actually my e-mail address, so there is nothing to confuse.

> How would this benefit people that don't have control over their own e-mail domain (e.g. gmail/yahoo/msn)?

Google and Yahoo already support it:

- https://gmail.com/.well-known/host-meta
- http://www.google.com/s2/webfinger/?q=klimpong@gmail.com
- https://yahoo.com/.well-known/host-meta

Comment: As an OpenID consumer or provider? And wouldn't *all* consumers need to support this then, to avoid confusion? Like: how would you know when to use your email address, and when to use an OpenID URL? (Actually, I favor typing a URL with some dots over typing an email address with a Shift-2, uh, @-character. But then not everybody can choose their own OpenID URL. And true, some consumers need me to type the `http://` too, which I dislike.)

Comment: First as consumer, because it makes the stack overflow login process easier for me. All OpenID consumers supporting webfinger would be ideal, yes.

Comment: See update: host-meta is an official RFC now.

Comment: It's funny because on the original Yadis/OpenID mailing list it was endlessly asserted that users didn't want or were to be confused by email-like identifiers. And this is just a new kludge upon the homepage address verification scheme that OpenID actually is. (Slightly better than Mozillas zero-privacy BrowserID though). -- From SOs standpoint it might be relevant if this simplification undermines the barrier of entry for technic-illiterate posters. (OpenID was once [portrayed as quality filter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226/148103) though there's a strong urge for usability.)

Comment: How would this benefit people that don't have control over their own e-mail domain (e.g. gmail/yahoo/msn)? IOW, this won't work unless the metadata can actually be found. I guess it could be silently supported, but I'm not sure about adopted and advertised.

Comment: Or are you more suggesting that Stack Exchange (as an OpenID provider) should support it? The [protocol](http://code.google.com/p/webfinger/wiki/WebFingerProtocol) itself is extremely simple.

Comment: Both if possible :)